# Are there opensource alternative for StreamBase?

Tags: open-source

I worked with [StreamBase](http://www.streambase.com/) in a previous life, and found it to be very useful for processing streams. However I can't afford StreamBase for a project I'm doing now, but if there is an open-source alternative I'd like to give it a spin. My other solution was to hack together a StreamBase like application using SQLite, but that'll take some time, and I don't have that sort of time right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might look into [EsperTech: Event Series Intelligence](http://www.espertech.com/esper)

Comment: Seems ok, but waiting to see if anything else comes up, before accepting as answer.

Comment: @[Robert Gould]: no rush, i'm curious if there is anything else like it out there also

Answer (score 1):

Quite different from StreamBase, but there is an OpenSource stream processing engine called [Storm](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm):

> Storm is a distributed realtime computation system. Similar to how
>   Hadoop provides a set of general primitives for doing batch
>   processing, Storm provides a set of general primitives for doing
>   realtime computation.

I've not used it myself but it looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle CQL does more or less the same thing as StreamBase, minus the GUI stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There are several open source options for stream processing in the meantime, e.g. Apache Storm, Apache Spark or Apache Samza.

However, they do not have the "things you found very useful" with StreamBase, probably. StreamBase has powerful but easy tooling for development, testing, deployment and monitoring.

Take a look at my blog post respectively article for more details about different stream processing and streaming analytics solutions (open source and proprietary):

[Comparison of Stream Processing and Streaming Analytics Alternatives (Apache Storm, Spark, IBM InfoSphere Streams, TIBCO StreamBase, Software AG Apama)](http://www.kai-waehner.de/blog/2014/09/10/comparison-stream-processing-streaming-analytics-alternatives-apache-storm-spark-ibm-infosphere-streams-tibco-streambase-sag-apama/)